# Loading an image from web-service on to an UIImage doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, dispatch-async

I have got a `productImageArray` that contains url as elements of the array.
I'm trying to load those urls in my image view.

Following is the way as of how I'm loading it.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        spinner.center=CGPointMake(160.0,240.0 );
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
        [self.view addSubview:spinner];
        [spinner startAnimating];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
             NSData *storeImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productImageArray[indexPath.row]]];
            self.productImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:storeImageData];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [spinner stopAnimating];
            });
        });
```

The problem is that,

1. Only the last cell of my tableview loads the image whereas the remaining cell does not load the image from the url
2. Is there any other better way of loading the image from url directly into my UIImage using native methods?

When I use  the following code, each cell of my tableview loads the image data but still it freezes the User interface till the data is loaded completely

```
NSData *storeImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productImageArray[indexPath.row]]];

        self.productImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:storeImageData];
```

Comment: put `self.productImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:storeImageData];` in main queue.

Comment: if you use AFNetworking webservice?

Comment: No im not using afnetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         NSData *storeImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productImageArray[indexPath.row]]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [spinner stopAnimating];
              self.productImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:storeImageData];
        });
    });
```

or try like

```
self.productImage.image = nil;   //// [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];

 NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productImageArray[indexPath.row]] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (data) {
        UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if (currentImage) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UITableviewCell *getCurrentCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if (getCurrentCell)
                     self.productImage.image = currentImage;
            });
        }
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: yes i have tried it but still the first cell has not loaded the image and its still emty

Comment: i tried it but it results in duplication of cells and also few cells remains unloaded.

Comment: can you udated question once

Comment: There are totally two cells but its showing 4 cells or 6 cells sometimes and few cells has got their image view unloaded sometimes

Comment: may be your image size is big ,

Answer (score 1):

@Anbu.Karthik answer is right.

But, maybe the simplest solution is to use something like `SDWebImage` no? This library will handle this issue and much more (cache, error management, proper tableview cells handling, ...).

I think you should, at least, take a few minutes to look at it: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

**Edit:**

If you use `SDWebImage`, and `UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage`, you can replace your entire code by this:

```
   [self.productImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productImageArray[indexPath.row]]
                      usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

More informations on `UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage`: https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage

Comment: welcome bro, if you want to easiest ansewer , use onejjy answer , SDWebImage is good one for cache

Comment: I added an example that fits completely the original code.

Comment: im gettting No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:usingActivityIndicatorStyle:'

Comment: Did you add the 2 mentioned libraries to your project ? Did you import it ?

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *url_Img1 = @"Your url";   
  Uiimageview *view_Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_Img1]]];
```

Comment: yup but it takes time to load it and hence the entire ui is getting frozen

Comment: I don't think that's a good solution. Indeed, you are loading the image into the main thread. So, UI Will be completely frozen during all the downloading process.

Comment: You can do like that using sd_webimage    [imgprofile sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[ResponseFriendList valueForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"profile_pic"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"]];

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.